# Why the end of result list is not []?

Tags: prolog

> I tried to output a list only contain the unique element. But the result is not perfect.

```
list_concatenation([],L,L).
list_concatenation([X1|L1],L2,[X1|L3]) :-
    list_concatenation(L1,L2,L3).

list_member(X, [X|_]).
list_member(X, [_|TAIL]) :- list_member(X,TAIL),!.

toset([],_).
toset([X|TAIL],SET):-
    list_member(X,SET),
    toset(TAIL,SET).
toset([X|TAIL],SET):-
    \+ list_member(X,SET),
    list_concatenation([X],SET,NEWSET),
    toset(TAIL,NEWSET).
```

For example:
`?- toset([1,1,2,3],X).`

> the result should be `'X = [1, 2, 3]'` but now, it is `'X = [1, 2, 3|_16998]'`

Comment: `toset([],_).` - the result of converting an empty list to a set of unique elements can be any value at all?

Answer (score 1):

You actually implement the `toset/2` the wrong way. You actually use `list_member/2` here to add an element to the list. Indeed, if you use a free variable, you get:

```
?- list_member(2, L).
L = [2|_3616] ;
L = [_3614, 2|_3622].
```

The `list_member/2` itself, is not correctly implemented as well. The cut (`!`) here prevents to keep yielding values. You thus should remove the cut:

```
list_member(X, [X|_]).
list_member(X, [_|Tail]) :-
    list_member(X,Tail).
```

This thus can yield all possible lists where `2` is a member:

```
?- list_member(2, L).
L = [2|_3412] ;
L = [_3410, 2|_3418] ;
L = [_3410, _3416, 2|_3424] ;
L = [_3410, _3416, _3422, 2|_3430] ;
...
```

But now the problem still remains: you should not use `list_member/2` here to add elements to the list, you can use an accumulator here that keeps track of the elements already yielded, and then eventually return that accumulator, like:

```
toset(L, S) :-
    toset(L, [], S).
toset([], A, S):-
    reverse(A, S).
toset([H|T], A, L) :-
    (  member_list(H, A)
    -> toset(T, [H|A], L)
    ;  toset(T, A, L)
    ).
```

We thus keep prepending the values to the accumulator, and in the end, we [**`reverse/2`** [swi-doc]](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=reverse/2) the accumulator, and return that as a result.